# How to get distance between one point and all other points in a table?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a table in Postgres with lat and long columns. Can I use the `ST_Distance_Sphere` or `ST_Distance_Spheroid` methods to get the distance between one point and all other points in the table? Do I first have to convert my existing lat/long to the Point datatype; if so is there any method to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, and the PostGIS documentation page for [ST_Distance_Sphere](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) and [ST_Distance_Sphereoid](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) both contain good examples. Here's one with lon/lat values plugged in to the ST_Point function:

```
SELECT 
     st_distance_sphere(
           st_point(-69.23, 44.61), st_point(-75.42, 43.55)
     )
```

The result in this example is 508166.687378974 meters.

To make the calculation from a given point to other in a "lon_lat" table you would just do the following:

```
SELECT 
    st_distance_sphere(
        st_point(-69.23, 44.61), st_point(lon_lat.lon, lon_lat.lat)
    )
FROM
    lon_lat
```

Answer (score 4):

In the line with [katahdin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4119/katahdin) answer, to calculate the distance to ALL other locations in your table, and assuming you have some kind of id in your rows, you can use something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    g1.id,
    g2.id,
    st_distance_sphere(
        st_point(g1.lon,g1.lat),st_point(g2.lon,g2.lat)
    )
FROM
    lon_lat as g1,
    lon_lat as g2
WHERE 
    g1.id != g2.id
```